# Create JSON with POST Angular JS

Tags: json, angularjs, forms, post, crud

I'm creating an app that create a JSON file (with a form).
I want you to take me through the controller form data (once I send) and I keep them in a JSON file with POST.

I explain... I have a form in which I put X data. These data have to be passed in JSON format a fichero.json using the POST method using Angular. I must say that it is a local file (currently not attack an external API), save data to a local fichero.json
Here my controller and HTML file:

```js
var app = angular.module('project', []);

app.controller('projectController', ['$http', controllerPost]);
function controllerPost($http){
    var cP = this;
    cP.formData = {};
    //declarar funcion enviar
    cP.sendPost = function(){
        $http.post("volcado.json", cP.formData)
            .success(function(response){
                console.log('Success', cP.formData.topicTitle, cP.formData.topicDesc, cP.formData.topicTTL);
            })
            .error(function(response){
                console.log("Error", response);
            })
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="form" ng-controller="projectController as cP">
    <form ng-submit="cP.sendPost()">
      <fieldset>
       <legend>Crear nuevo topic</legend>
        <table border>
          <tr>
            <td>Titulo topic:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="topicTitle" id="topicTitle" ng-model="cP.formData.topicTitle" required></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Descripcion topic:<td>
              <input type="text" name="topicDesc" id="topicDesc" ng-model="cP.formData.topicDesc" required></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>TTL topic:
              <td><input type="text" name="topicTTL" id="topicTTL" ng-model="cP.formData.topicTTL"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan=2>
              <input type="reset" >
              <input type="submit" value="Crear topic">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: put this in the question section.  A question has a question mark.

Comment: The code it's works. The problem was that i need a backend with api rest. I had created de backend with spring and my app it's working.